# Cypher - aggregating nodes by string in a property

Tags: java, twitter, neo4j, cypher

H all, I have a neo4j database, each node is a tweet with user informations. I have to build a social network using mentions in each tweet. the relevant properties are user_name and tweet_user_mention. my strategy:

1. get all nodes.
2. for each nodes, get username and use it in query for getting a group of nodes have that string in tweet_user_mention
3. create oriented edges between nodes.

example:

```
*username to search: (node: {user_name: 'goofy' [...]})
*query -> match (n) where (tweet_user_mention: 'goofy') return n; get all nodes that mention 'goofy'.
*create links.
```

The problem I'm trying to put is that a node may have multiple mentions, and I don't know how to query on multiple mentions without knowing how many.

Now a node can have for example:

```
1 mention
tweet_user_mention_0: 'goofy'

3 mentions
tweet_user_mention_0: 'goofy_0'
tweet_user_mention_1: 'goofy_1'
tweet_user_mention_2: 'goofy_2'
...
n mentions
tweet_user_mention_n: 'goofy_n'
```

it is better to concatenate strings and keep them in a single property like this?

```
3 mentions
tweet_user_mentions: 'goofy_0 goofy_1 goofy_2'
How could it be the query? have I to user regex in cypher?
```

Thanks all.

I've edited my question. is clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you know the 'mentions' when you create the nodes since you set one or more 'mention properties'. Could you not just create the relationships then?

If you need to set properties first and then create relationships, use only one property but let it be an array. Flattening the properties to something like `mention_1`, `mention_2` etc is a pain since in Cypher it's not possible (or at least very inconvenient) to work with property names dynamically. Using regexp is also inconvenient, error prone and slow. It is better in this case to use a string array. You can then loop over the values of the array property in a `FOREACH` clause, or match individual values from the array with `IN`. Downside is that the label indices currently don't support arrays, which could make things very slow for you if you do many lookups in the `tweet_user_mention` array. I think the indices will support arrays/collections soon, but I don't work for Neo4j so don't take my word for it.

With 'mentions' as a string array you could do things sort of like this

```
//CREATE
CREATE (:User {username: 'goofy1'}), (:User {username: 'goofy2'})
, (:Tweet {tweet_user_mention: ['goofy0', 'goofy1']})

//MATCH all tweets and make sure they have relationships to the users they mention
MATCH (t:Tweet)
FOREACH (user_mentioned IN (t.tweet_user_mention) | 
    MERGE (mentioned:User {username:user_mentioned})
    MERGE t-[:MENTIONS]->mentioned
)

//MATCH tweets mentioning specific username and merge the relationship to that user
MATCH (t:Tweet)
WHERE 'goofy0' IN t.tweet_user_mention
MERGE (u:User {username: 'goofy0'})
MERGE t-[:MENTIONS]->u
```

Comment: I also thought to use the tweet as property of the edge between users. I'm using twitter4j and a listener to collect tweets with the streaming api. Is also difficult to create relationships when a tweet is captured, because then i have to test if the user is present in database, later create edges. If not, create an empty node than update it if i found him in another tweet .. mmm .. i think is better listen for hashtag, collect tweets, on stop create edges and possible empty nodes like users who have not interacted, but only mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can model mentions not as properties but rather as relationships. Then you can just select all the relationships of the specified type.

Let user and tweet be the types if nodes. Then, for example, user1 can have relation of type Author to the tweet node #1, and tweet #1 can have relationship of type Mentions to user2.